# Proving $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}^2\frac{4H_{2n}-3H_n}{n2^{4n}}=\zeta(2)$

Tags: calculus, integration, summation, binomial-coefficients, harmonic-numbers

While trying to solve [Prove $\int_{0}^{1}\frac1k K(k)\ln\left[\frac{\left(1+k \right)^3}{1-k} \right]\text{d}k=\frac{\pi^3}{4}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4777682/prove-int-01-frac1k-kk-ln-left-frac-left1k-right31-k-right)

I was able to reduce it to the following form,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}^2\frac{4H_{2n}-3H_n}{n2^{4n}}=\zeta(2)$$
Where, $H_n$ is the $n$th Harmonic Number.

This should be correct if I did all the steps correctly, but I am unable to prove this further.


I tried searching more about series of this form which have the Central Binomial Coefficient Squared with Harmonic Numbers but was not able to find any.


Any help would be appreciated.


EDIT:


Considering,
$$M(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\left(\frac{2K\left(\sqrt{s}\right)-\pi}{s}\right)ds$$
where $K(k)$ is the Complete Elliptical Integral of the First Kind.

Then the question is reducible to,
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{M\left(1\right)+3M\left(x\right)-4M\left(x^{2}\right)}{1-x}dx=\frac{\pi^3}{6}$$
Though no idea comes to mind after this.

Here are some related results:
$$M(1)=4\pi\ln2-8G$$
$$\int_{0}^{1}M\left(x\right)dx=-8G-4+\pi+4\pi\ln2$$

where $G$ is Catalan's Constant.


EDIT:

Let,
$$A=\Im \operatorname{Li_{3}}\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)$$
where $\operatorname{Li_{3}}(.)$ is the trilogarithm.


and $G$ be the Catalan's Constant.


Using the Twin Integrals Mentioned in the Post at the Beginning, was able to arrive at these.
$$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\binom{2r}{r}^2\frac{H_{2n}}{n2^{4n}}=24\frac{G\ln2}{\pi}+48\frac{A}{\pi}-\frac{3}{2}\ln\left(2\right)^{2}-\frac{29}{24}\pi^{2}$$
$$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\binom{2r}{r}^2\frac{H_{n}}{n2^{4n}}=32\frac{G\ln2}{\pi}+64\frac{A}{\pi}-2\ln\left(2\right)^{2}-\frac{5}{3}\pi^{2}$$

Comment: I hope, @AliShadhar will come and help you.

Comment: Related https://mathoverflow.net/questions/323287/is-it-true-that-sum-k-1-infty-frac-binom2kk2k16kh-2k-h-k-frac2/332643#332643

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**A fast and simple solution idea by Cornel Ioan Valean**

We will use the power of the ideas and strategies from the books **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series (2019)** and **More (Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series (2023)**.

**Okay, let's start!**

From the book, **More (Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series (2023)**, Sect. $4.5$, pages $396$-$398$, we have that
$$\displaystyle \color{blue}{-\frac{\log(1-x^2)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{2n} \frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}(2 H_{2n}-H_n),\ |x|<1} ,$$
and exploiting this fact and turning the left-hand side into a double integral, $\displaystyle \int _0^{\pi/2}\left(\int _0^{\sin (x)}\frac{\log \left(1-y^2\right)}{y\sqrt{1-y^2}}\textrm{d}y\right)\textrm{d}x$, immediately reveals (after changing the integration order) that
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \binom{2 n}{n}^2 \frac{2 H_{2 n}-H_n}{n 2^{4 n}}$$
$$ =\frac{\pi^2}{2}+\frac{16}{\pi }\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x) \log(1-x)}{x} \textrm{d}x+\frac{16}{\pi }\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x) \log(1+x)}{x} \textrm{d}x$$
$$-\frac{16}{\pi }\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(x) \log(1+x^2)}{x} \textrm{d}x. \tag1$$

On the other hand, exploiting that
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \log(\sin(x)) \sin^{2n}(x) \textrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\binom{2n}{n}\left(H_{2n}-H_n-\log(2)\right),$$
which is also found in the sequel, page $191$, multiplying both sides by $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n 2^{2n}}\binom{2n}{n}$, making the summation from $n=1$ to $\infty$, and rearranging, we get that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}^2\frac{H_{2n}-H_n-\log(2)}{n 2^{4n}}$$
$$\small =-\frac{8 }{\pi }\int_0^1 \frac{\log ^2(1+x^2)}{1+x^2} \textrm{d}x+\frac{8 }{\pi } \log (2)\int_0^1 \frac{ \log(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\textrm{d}x$$
$$+\frac{8 }{\pi }\int_0^1 \frac{\log(x) \log(1+x^2)}{1+x^2} \textrm{d}x.\tag2$$

The rest is known and trivial, and the separate series involving the numbers $H_{2n}$ and $H_n$ are extracted by a system of relation consisting of $(1)$ and $(2)$.

**End of story**

Thank you so much **Cornel** for your work and your life-changing books, **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series (2019)** and **More (Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series (2023)**.

**(Very) important:** Exploiting such techniques involving the series in blue for building systems of relations, one can derive extremely difficult series. Some (simple) paper(s) showing such examples will be written soon.

**Update 1:** Indeed, the series taken apart also contain a Trilogarithm with a complex argument. The forms of the two key identities (that is, using integrals) avoid that appearance, and to get directly the desired value without touching the Trilogarithm with a complex argument, all we need is to turn the integrals from the identity in $(2)$ into arctan-log integrals. Then we need to exploit the arctan-log integral identities given in the sequel, Sects. $1.36$-$1.38$, pages $48$-$51$. **That's all (and done)!**

**Update 2:** A full solution with all the details of this problem will be found soon in a separate paper (the main series plus the two separated series).

**Update 3:** [Binoharmonic Series with the Squared Central Binomial Coefficient And Their Integral Transformation Using Elliptic Integrals by Cornel Ioan Valean](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/374739982)

Comment: Unique as always (+1). Cornel is a really nice guy he helped me a lot with many issues I came across especially with writing my book.

Comment: (+1) Amazing Answer! As a side note do you think relation between these could shorten the solutions.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}^2\frac{H_{2n}}{n2^{4n}}=-\frac{4}{\pi}\cdot\bigg(\int_{0}^{1}\frac{K(k)\ln(1-k)}{k}dk\bigg)-\frac{1}{3}\pi^2$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}^2\frac{H_{n}-H_{2n}}{n2^{4n}}=-\frac{4}{\pi}\cdot\bigg(\int_{0}^{1}\frac{K\left(k\right)\ln\left(1+k\right)}{k}dk\bigg)+\frac{1}{6}\pi^{2}$$
Though I am not aware how to calculate these integrals.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *Update 2*, are you perhaps publishing a paper on this? If so where may I read it.
Also, found this series.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}^2\frac{H_{n-\frac{1}{2}}}{(2n-1)2^{4n}}=2\left(\frac{4}{\pi}-1\right)\ln2$$

Comment: I mean that once such a paper is uploaded on ResearchGate, the related link will also be added here in the answer above (as an update). Now, I'm not a great fan of the specific notation of the harmonic number when the argument is not a non-negative integer number - maybe it is more natural to be viewed by the Digamma function. Anyway, that number equals $2 H_{2n} - H_{n} - 2 \log(2)$ and hence the relation in blue can be immediately employed and the calculations are very simple - one immediately arrives at the result in your comment.

Comment: @AliShadhar Thank you, Ali! And you are really nice sharing these thoughts!

Comment: @BlackEmperor Thank you! For some reason, I missed your first comment. If you multiply the relation $(2)$ in the answer above by $2$ and add it to the relation $(1)$, you *almost* get the initial series in OP. At the moment, I see that for keeping all in terms of elegance, we might need to exploit relations with arctan-log integrals, that is to totally avoid that not-so-nice trilogarithmic part. I didn't check the details of your proposal in the comments, but I might ponder on it later.