# Ramanujan-Type Harmonic Series $\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\binom{2r}{r}^3\left(\frac{1/6+r}{2^{8r}}\right)H_{r-1/2}=-\frac{8\ln2}{9\pi}$

Tags: integration, summation, generating-functions, harmonic-numbers, elliptic-integrals

We will be considering series such as this :

$$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\binom{2r}{r}^3\left(\frac{1/6+r}{2^{8r}}\right)H_{r-1/2}=-\frac{8\ln2}{9\pi}$$

---

Consider $K(k)$ and $E(k)$ to be the Complete Elliptical Integrals of the First and Second Kind Respectively with $K'(k)=K(k')$ and $E'(k)=E(k')$, where $k^2+k'^2=1$.

First let us consider the following Generating Functions:

$$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\binom{2r}{r}^2\frac{H_r}{2^{4r}}k^{2r}=K'(k)+\frac{2K(k)}{\pi}\ln\left(\frac{k}{4k'}\right)$$

$$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\binom{2r}{r}^2\frac{H_{2r}}{2^{4r}}k^{2r}=\frac{K'(k)}{2}+\frac{2K(k)}{\pi}\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{k}}{2k'}\right)$$

Now one may let $k\to k\sin t$ and Integrate from $0$ to $\pi/2$ with respect to $t$.

$$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\binom{2r}{r}^3\left(\frac{H_r}{2^{6r}}\right)(2kk')^{2r}=\frac{4K(k)K'(k)}{3\pi}+\frac{8K^2(k)}{3\pi^2}\ln(kk'/4)-\frac{2v(2kk')}{\pi^2}$$

$$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\binom{2r}{r}^3\left(\frac{H_{2r}}{2^{6r}}\right)(2kk')^{2r}=\frac{2K(k)K'(k)}{3\pi}+\frac{4K^2(k)}{3\pi^2}\ln(kk'/4)-\frac{2v(2kk')}{\pi^2}$$
where,
$$v(k)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}K(k\sin t)\ln(1-k^{2}\sin^{2}t)dt$$

What's troublesome here is the function $v(k)$, I am not able reduce it further.

At the very least we can find the Generating Function for $H_{n}-H_{2n}=\overline{H}_{2n}$ which is the Skew Harmonic Number (As the Function $v(k)$ cancels out).

$$\pi\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\binom{2r}{r}^3\left(\frac{\overline{H}_{2r}}{2^{6r}}\right)(2kk')^{2r}=\frac{2}{3}K(k)K'(k)+\frac{4}{3\pi}\ln(kk'/4)K^2(k)$$

Now we differentiate here and write everything in Terms of $k_n$, $\alpha_n,\beta_n$.

Where $k_n$ is the [Elliptic Integral Singular Value](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValue.html) such that $K'/K=\sqrt{n}$.
$\alpha_n$ is the Elliptic Alpha Function.

and $\beta_n$ is defined by us as $$\beta_n=\ln(k_nk'_n/4)$$

Now,

$$\pi\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\binom{2r}{r}^3\left(\frac{\overline{H}_{2r}}{2^{6r}}\right)(2k_nk'_n)^{2r}=\frac{2}{3}K_n^2\left(\sqrt{n}+\frac{2\beta_n}{\pi}\right)$$

and,
$$\pi\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\binom{2r}{r}^3\left(\frac{\overline{H}_{2r}}{2^{6r}}\right)r(2k_nk'_n)^{2r}=\frac{2}{3}K_n^2\left(\frac{1}{\pi}+\left(\frac{\alpha_n-k_n^2\sqrt{n}}{2k_n^2-1}\right)\left(1+\frac{2\beta_n}{\pi\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)-\frac{\beta_n}{3(2k_n^2-1)\sqrt{n}}$$

Although we cannot Eliminate $K_n$ by taking a Linear Combination, we can remove the Algebraic Term attached with $K_n$.

This gives us:

$$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\binom{2r}{r}^3\left(\frac{\overline{H}_{2r}}{2^{6r}}\right)(2k_nk'_n)^{2r}\left(\frac{k_n^{2}-\alpha_n/\sqrt{n}}{k_n^2-k'^2_n}+r\right)=\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\frac{2K^2_n}{3\pi}-\frac{\beta_n}{3\sqrt{n}(k_n^2-k_n'^2)}\right)$$

Some Particular Evaluations of these using $k_3k'_3=1/4$, $k_7k'_7=1/16$ are:

$$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\binom{2r}{r}^3\left(\frac{\color{blue}{1/6}+r}{2^{8r}}\right)\overline{H}_{2r}=\frac{2}{3\pi}\left(\frac{K^2(k_{3})}{\pi}\ -\frac{4\ln2}{3}\right)$$

$$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\binom{2r}{r}^3\left(\frac{\color{blue}{5/42}+r}{2^{12r}}\right)\overline{H}_{2r}=\frac{8}{21\pi}\left(\frac{7K^2(k_{7})}{4\pi}-2\ln2\right)$$

And recall Ramanujan's Famous Series for $\pi$:
$$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\binom{2r}{r}^3\left(\frac{\color{blue}{1/6}+r}{2^{8r}}\right)=\frac{2}{3\pi}$$

$$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\binom{2r}{r}^3\left(\frac{\color{blue}{5/42}+r}{2^{12r}}\right)=\frac{8}{21\pi}$$

Which is Interesting, I am guessing the Algebraic Term along with $r$ also appears in the Derivation of these Series.

This got me thinking that although we do not have the closed form of Generating Functions for $H_r$ and $H_{2r}$ (due to function $v(x)$) so instead I set up to use Integer Relation Algorithms which surprisingly gives.

$$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\binom{2r}{r}^3\left(\frac{1/6+r}{2^{8r}}\right)H_{r}=\frac{4}{3\pi}\left(\frac{K^2(k_{3})}{\pi}\ -\ln2\right)$$

$$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\binom{2r}{r}^3\left(\frac{1/6+r}{2^{8r}}\right)H_{2r}=\frac{2}{9\pi}\left(\frac{3K^2(k_{3})}{\pi}\ -2\ln2\right)$$

Nothing for the case of $k_7$. (If it involves roots then I don't know how to use Integer Relations).

This means we have a certain Hope of Evaluating $v(k)$.
Both of the above equations are analogous to:
$$2v\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+3v'\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=-\frac{8\pi \ln2}{3}\tag{1}$$

In fact now we can take a Linear Combination to Eliminate $K^2(k_3)$ as follows:

$$\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\binom{2r}{r}^3\left(\frac{1/6+r}{2^{8r}}\right)(2H_{2r}-H_r)=\frac{4\ln2}{9\pi}$$

Which is a good start.

If one wants something fancier then use $H_{n-1/2}=2H_{2n}-H_{n}-2\ln2$ to get:

$$\boxed{\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\binom{2r}{r}^3\left(\frac{1/6+r}{2^{8r}}\right)H_{r-1/2}=-\frac{8\ln2}{9\pi}}$$

Questions:

1. Do we know anything about the Function $v(k)$?
   The question about Generating Functions for Cubed Binomial $H_{r}$ and $H_{2r}$ has been considered in this post [Generating function of the sequence $\binom{2n}{n}^3H_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2613728/generating-function-of-the-sequence-binom2nn3h-n?noredirect=1) but no response so far.
2. Can we prove $(1)$?
3. Like the Higher Order Variations of the $1/\pi^m$ Series, are higher order variations of the Binomial Harmonic Sums been considered anywhere in Literature?

Comment: Does $v(k)$ want to means $v(x)$ ? Best.

Comment: @User Yes! I will edit it that's a mistake.

Comment: It seems my MO answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436205) would be enough to answer your questions (1) and (2), which covers them as special cases. As for (3), there are many such sums, many can be proved using WZ-method, again I refer you to above linked MO question.

Comment: @pisco Thank you for the comment, it seems I would have to study that answer for a while as it's above my level.

Comment: @pisco Is WZ-method omnipotent? Some convergence rate involves algebraics like $\sqrt{2}-1$. There exist some choices associated with such algebraics, but they usually lead to  complicated certificates.

Comment: @SetnessRamesory WZ-method can't currently prove certain identities that involve deep arithmetic value of modular forms (e.g. Ramanujan $1/\pi$-formulas). The certificates are always complicated even when all numbers are rational.

Comment: @pisco It gives me a strong sense that WZ-method has a lot of unravelled mysteries.

Comment: What exactly is $v'(k)$?
I thought that it's either the derivative or the complementary variant of $v(k)$, namely:
$$v'(k)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}K(k'\sin t)\ln(1-(k')^{2}\sin^{2}t)dt$$

I'd suggest to simply include the integral variant of $2v\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+3v'\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=-\frac{8\pi \ln2}{3}$ in the question directly since it might help to read Q2 easier (without going through the series).

Comment: @Zacky In this case $v'(k)$ is really the derivative. Though I haven't been able to do anything much about this function. Originally I thought it might get evaluated as the product of two Elliptic Integrals (As is case in some other Integrals of $K$)

Comment: We can obtain the following:
$$\small 2v(1/2)+3v'(1/2)=\frac{12\pi}{\sqrt 3}\ln\left(\frac34\right)+12\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x^2/4)}{\sqrt{1-x^2/4}}\frac{E'(x)-K'(x)}{1-x^2}dx+4\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x^2/4)}{\sqrt{1-x^2/4}} K'(x)dx$$
Now, we might have a lot of success like in this [approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4868885/515527) if two integral representations are found for $\ln(1-x^2/4) K'(x)$ and $\ln(1-x^2/4)(E'(x)-K'(x))$.

Comment: Can you please add a reference to formulas for the Generating Functions in lines 2 and 3?

Answer (score 3):

**Not an answer.**

Only to give you a related formula. It can be proven also.
$$\frac{2}{\pi}K(k)=4\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}^2\frac{n^3k^{2n-2}H_{n}}{2^{4n}(2n-1)^2}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}^2\frac{(n+1)k^{2n}H_{n}}{2^{4n}}\tag{1}.$$
Multiplying both sides of $(1)$ by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^2}}
$ and integrating in $(0,1)$ gives the very slow convergent series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}^3\frac{(4n^3+6n^2-5n+1)H_{n}}{2^{6n}(2n-1)^3}=\frac{\pi}{\Gamma(3/4)^4}\tag{2}.$$
Others with better convergence can be obtained:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}^3\frac{(24n^4+4n^3+6n^2-5n+1)H_{n}}{2^{8n}(2n-1)^3}=\frac{108^{1/6}\Gamma{(1/3)}^6}{8\pi^4}\tag{3}.$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}^3\frac{(72n^4-4n^3-6n^2+5n-1)(-1)^{n}H_{n}}{2^{9n}(1-2n)^3}=\frac{32\sqrt{2}\Gamma{(5/4)}^4}{\pi^3}\tag{4}.$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}^3\frac{(504n^4+4n^3+6n^2-5n+1)H_{n}}{2^{12n}(2n-1)^3}=\frac{\Gamma{(1/7)}^2\Gamma{(2/7)}^2\Gamma{(4/7)}^2}{4\sqrt{7}\pi^{4}}\tag{5}.$$
As you see with $(1)$ seems that $\log{2}$ disappears and maybe you will arrive to series for $1/\pi$ involving also harmonic coefficients.
Seeing the relation pattern with Ramanujan's series for the theory $s=1/2$ seems that we have associated series involving also harmonic numbers in the general terms.

---

As we said there is a counter part for Ramanujan's series for $1/\pi$, here is one example:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}^3\frac{p(n)(-1)^{n+1}H_{n}}{2^{9n}(2n-1)^3}=\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{\pi}\tag{6},$$
where $p(n)=432n^5-336n^4-40n^3+24n^2-n-1$.

Comment: Nice! I see that $(1)$ is the Original Series of $K(k)$ but shifted to include Harmonic Terms.

Comment: @MiracleInvoker I will update some on this and try to answer your question. Deal with $v(k)$ seems to be doable. Best all.